# 4. 0 (API 14) SDK platform is "Obsolete"! Should I still manage to download and use it?

Tags: android

I am making an Android app. I want it will support Android 4.0 or above. But when I try to download Android 4.0 (API 14) SDK Platform in SDK Manager, I found the version of SDK was marked as "Obsolete".

Now I wonder whether I could download and use the SDK Platform and System Images for this obsolete version of SDK. Although the target version of my app is API 18 (4.3), I just want to test my app in Android 4.0.

By the way, I wonder whether my utility app should support Android 3.0 (API 11). I am not clear about the share for Android 3.0/3.1/3.2 in current Android-based mobiles and tablets market.

Comment: Download the latest stable APIs, Android 21 and target it. You do not need to download the older SDKs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it is marked as obsolete is because there are almost no devices using this API. Most of the devices running Android 4.0 version are actually running 4.0.3 or 4.0.4 which is considered as API level 15.

You can find the latest official stats from Google on API levels here:
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

There's no info on Android 3.x, though, because it was a tablet-specific version of Android. There were no phones running Android 3.x. It's safe to ignore it.

And unless you're developing for a market with high percentage of older devices, I think it's safe to ignore API lower than 15 as well.

Comment: To get 95% of the market, I would suggest your "max" minSDK to be 14.

Comment: Api level 15, not 14. 14 has less than 0.1% of all devices which is mentioned on the page I linked.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I said 14 as in "Ice Creamsandwich", so you can support a range from API 14 to 22. For instance, if you were to support gingerbread you can support API 9 and 10.

Comment: I see now. Thanks to Ilya Polenov and Jared Burrows. Happy weekend.